# Move RAID1 to new machine

Tags: migration, raid

I have an older server with `/` on one hard drive and `/srv` on a RAID1 partition, which I remember took some time to set up (I set it up after the installation). I will be installing Ubuntu 10.04 onto a new server, but would like to take the `/srv` hard drives to the new machine.

What steps need to be taken to ensure a complete and proper migration? Should I tell the installer about the additional drives, or connect them after setup has completed?

For reference, I will be installing the "Standard" Ubuntu desktop, and adding server applications, rather than installing a "Server" Ubuntu and adding desktop applications.

Comment: do you want to install ubuntu on a NEW server, or do you want to upgrade the EXISTING server with a new OS?

Comment: I am installing Ubuntu on a new computer, and will be physically moving two hard drives from the old server to the new one and would like to keep them RAIDed.

Answer (score 5):

I checked in a VirtualBox: The Desktop Installer **does not recognize** existing mdadm Raid1 devices.

You should

- install ubuntu
- plugin the 2 raid hdds **afterwards**.
- (you should **reboot** to be on the safe side)
- Then install mdadm with `sudo apt-get install mdadm`
- `cat /proc/mdstat` You should see your inactive RAID
- `sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md_d0 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1` (change the `sdb1` and `sdc1` to your raid partitions)
- `sudo mdadm --detail --scan`

The output on my system is:

```
  berni@virtual2:~$ sudo mdadm --detail --scan
  ARRAY /dev/md/d0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=00.90 UUID=bcb40263:0fe2be0e:4a925ea7:19eea675
```

- Copy the whole `ARRAY ..` line to the end of `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`
- Now your raidconfig is preserved and you can use `/dev/md0` as a normal device
- For example `sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/raid`

This stuff is working on Lucid & Maverick